# check for multiple if-statements

Tags: java, if-statement

Is it possible to do someting like:

```
if(...) {...}
  else {
  if(...) {...}
  if(...) {...}
  if(...) {...}
  }
     if(neither of these 3 if-statements are correct) {...}
```

or:

```
if(...) {...}
  else {
  if(...) {...} or
  if(...) {...} or
  if(...) {...} 
  }
     else {...} // if neither of the 3 if-statements above is correct
```

I know it would be possible to achieve the same thing with a lot of if-else statements, but if it works like above, it would look way cleaner.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to do this, but can you include any actual code?

Comment: use `switch` if you can

Comment: i don't know why you would but have you heard of || or &&

Comment: Please post the code in question. It's impossible to give a good answer using such an abstracted example, because we don't know what the expressions are that are being evaluated. If it's testing for equality of one field, use the `switch` statement. If it's a bunch of more-or-less unrelated expressions, use `if-then-else`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript: evaluating multiple if statements without also running else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49183317/javascript-evaluating-multiple-if-statements-without-also-running-else)

Comment: @EKW Using a Javascript question as the duplicate target for a **Java** is not desirable.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel My mistake. I misread the tags.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible using following structure.

```
if(...) {...
  }
  else {
       if(...) {
          ...
       } else if(...) {
       ...
       } else if(...) {
       ...
       } else {
       ...
       }       
  }
```

If you have constant expression switch case would be useful as well.

Comment: @DieNerd could you elaborate?